# GitHub Actions - run action triggered by merged pull request to main branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I've tried a variety of methods to accomplish this but none have worked.

I want to run a GitHub action on the main branch once the first workflow has been completed (which is running tests on development and merges to main if tests pass).

How can I go about doing this?

My folder structure looks like this:

```
|-- .github/workflows 
    | -- merge_to_main.yml
    | -- run_on_main.yml
```

When anyone pushes to `development`, it should run the `merge_to_main.yml` file.

Then if that file successfully runs, the `run_on_main.yml` file should be triggered to run on the main branch.

Comment: Don't you just need to do `on: push: branches: development` in `merge_to_main.yml` which will its test and finish by doing the actual merge and pushing, and then `on: push: branches: main` in `run_on_main.yml` will get triggered by that push in the first workflow?

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if I need to put the logic for both files into a single file. Then I can wait for a job to finish (the merge dev --> main job) before running the code on the run_on_main.yml file

Comment: Yes, you can certainly just add more steps in one file, that may be simpler, and it all gets triggered by the push on dev, and only continues as longs as steps are successful.

Comment: Thank you. This ended up working much better - I consolidated the two files into one. If you post your comment as an answer I can give you credit for the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to create just one workflow, with all the steps one after the other. Workflows only continue if the earlier steps are successful, so you know the merge will only happen if the earlier steps are successful, and the post-merge steps only if everything before was OK.

Then this whole sequence can be triggered by the push on `development` and you'll be set.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggering both workflow runs on the merge, trigger the first one on the merge and trigger the second one this way:

```
name: run_on_main

# Only trigger, when the other workflow succeeded
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["merge_to_main"]
    types:
      - completed
```

(This code is assuming the workflows are named after the file names. if your names are different you will need to swap those in)